# Open multiple apps from screen of one app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want open multiple apps which are developed by me. I know we can do that thro custome Url. But in that case it installs app on my device. I want do open app through only my app.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to perform this same task some time ago , and all i could recommend is that you look into the Three20 framework... you can find more info here.. http://three20.info/ it allows you create apps inside apps.

Comment: They are not really apps. They only make links to new views looks like app icons. It was mentioned in the Tech Talk 2011 (mark kawano) not to use too complicate hierarchy. It will confuse the user (bad architecture)

Comment: may be that is what he wants to achieve... his question pretty much states the same requirements.. but thanks for the info.

Comment: @Rong It means it do same as we do through custom URLS?